# How to make PostgresQL optimizer to build execution plan AFTER binding parameters?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-optimization

I'm developing Pg/PLSQL function for PostgresQL 9.1. When I use variables in a SQL query, optimizer build a bad execution plan. But if I replace a variable by its value the plan is ok.
For instance:

```
v_param := 100;
select count(*)
  into result
  from <some tables>
 where <some conditions>
       and id = v_param
```

performed in 3s

and

```
select count(*)
  into result
  from <some tables>
 where <some conditions>
       and id = 100
```

performed in 300ms

In first case optimizer generate a fixed plan for any value of **v_param**.

In second case optimizer generate a plan based on specified value and it's significantly more efficient despite not using plan caching.

Is it possible to make optimizer to generate plan without dynamic binding and generate a plan every time when I execute the query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been dramatically improved by Tom Lane in the [just-released PostgreSQL 9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1415/); see [What's new in PostgreSQL 9.2](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2) particularly:

> Prepared statements used to be optimized once, without any knowledge
>   of the parameters' values. With 9.2, the planner will use specific
>   plans regarding to the parameters sent (the query will be planned at
>   execution), except if the query is executed several times and the
>   planner decides that the generic plan is not too much more expensive
>   than the specific plans.

This has been a long-standing and painful wart that's previously required `SET enable_...` params, the use of wrapper functions using `EXECUTE`, or other ugly hacks. Now it should "just work".

Upgrade.

For anyone else reading this, you can tell if this problem is biting you because `auto_explain` plans of parameterised / prepared queries will differ from those you get when you `explain` the query yourself. To verify, try `PREPARE ... SELECT` then `EXPLAIN EXECUTE` and see if you get a different plan to `EXPLAIN SELECT`.

See also [this prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825444/postgres-query-is-very-slow-when-using-a-parameter-instead-of-an-hardcoded-strin/10828675#10828675).

Comment: +1 for finding a perfect real-world example of the benefit described in the "What's New" doc which might not have caught everyone's eye. And for being almost ridiculously prompt (<24 hours since the 9.2 GA).

Comment: @mdahlman I've been excited about this feature [since Tom implemented it](http://lwn.net/Articles/497264/) and [pointing it out for a while](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10828675/398670). It's a small but great improvement that should help solve issues like [this](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2011-06/msg00799.php) transparently in future.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic queries doesn't use cached plans - so you can use EXECUTE USING statement in 9.1 and older. 9.2 should to work without this workaround as Craig wrote.

```
v_param := 100;
EXECUTE 'select count(*) into result from <some tables> where <some conditions>
   and id = $1' USING v_param;
```

Comment: +1 for a workaround that doesn't require upgrading to 9.2 yet. Nice.

Comment: Note that this only works within a PL/PgSQL function. Plain SQL `EXECUTE` is used to invoke prepared statements. I alluded to this in "wrapper functions using `EXECUTE`" but should've been more specific; thanks Pavel.

Comment: sure, SQL EXECUTE and PL/pgSQL EXECUTE are two different statements - this technique is not possible for prepared statements and it should be problem in some environments - PostgreSQL has nice functionality for once time execution *PQexecParams*, that can be used instead prepared statements in almost cases, but it is available only in some interfaces